# sum of calculated expression in rdlc report

Tags: report, rdlc, viewer

I want sum of salary column:

[image]

this is expr for salary column:

```
=iif(fields!Items.Value="A",(cdec(sum(fields!sumofincome.Value)/1000*3)), iif(fields!Items.Value="B",(cdec(sum(fields!sumofincome.Value)/1000*1.5)),iif(fields!Items.Value="C",(cdec(sum(fields!sumofincome.Value)/1000*0.5)),0)))`
```

Comment: I have a report matrix and i want to sum salary column. above code is for salary column.
please help me

Comment: What language + framework(s) are you working in?  [tag:excel]?  [tag:google-sheets]?  Somethine else?  Please [edit] your question and [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) it with the technologies you are using.  Doing so will attract the attention of people who can answer.  Generic tags like [tag:report] and [tag:viewer] are not useful.

Comment: in rdlc reporting in vs c#